# do I need to send my online access information if someone is depositing money into my account is this a scam?

Tags: scams, online-banking

I met someone online. She says she wants to help me with legal issues. She said her late father left her a business and she says she is selling the business and sending the money to my account. She says she needs:
my full name
my routing and account numbers 
Online information such as screen name and password.
is this a scam?

Comment: "Online information such as screen name and password."  **Never share your password!!!!**

Comment: Let me reiterate: **NEVER SHARE YOUR PASSWORD!!**

Comment: Ron - can you clarify? When is it ok to share passwords?

Comment: This is 100% absolutely for sure a **scam**.

Comment: We really need a big, red **WARNING: YOU ARE BEING SCAMMED** box to pop-up whenever someone types the phrase "_met someone online_", "_online friend_" or "_asked for my password_" into the question box.

Comment: Times like this I like to ask myself, then answer: Why does she want to put money in *my* account for this?  Why wouldn't she just put the money in her own account, or open a new one if absolutely necessary?  If this is real and above board, she doesn't need *you* to do it, and if it's not above board, you don't want to be involved.

Comment: "I met someone online."

Answer (score 13):

Yes, this is *always* a scam. Anyone you meet online who wants passwords to access your finances is trying to scam you.

There are a lot of different ways this can play out, but the most common is that the scammer is going to transfer tainted funds into and then out of your account. When the transfer into your account is reversed, you will be left with a negative balance.

https://www.fbi.gov/news/stories/fbi-joins-international-campaign-to-stop-money-mules-121718

Answer (score 2):

To make this very clear, from your financial institution's point of view, **there is no legitimate reason anyone except you should ever need your online banking username and password, for any purpose at all, ever.** This includes your financial institution, your friends, your relatives, and your employer - much less random strangers on the internet.

The financial industry has established, safe tools for legitimately moving money between accounts. This can be done via:

- Cash. Self explanatory.
- Paper check.
- Electronic transfer between banks, via ACH or other established protocol.
- Third party escrow service, such as Paypal.

**None** of these legitimate methods require the other party to know your online banking username and password.

Financial institutions also have methods for providing legitimate online banking access to your accounts for individuals who have a legitimate need for that access. So, even in the case where someone needs to access your finances, **it won't be by sharing your own username and password.** This can mean:

- You and your spouse are co-owners of a checking account, and your bank gives you each unique online banking access to the same account
- You're involved in managing a business's accounts, and the others with similar authority at your business all have unique logins to your bank's business banking website
- A lawyer or other party is designated as a custodian, trustee, or other non-owner role on an account that you are the owner of, and they are given their own credentials to access the account

Giving people access through these methods (vs sharing *your* username and password) allows your financial institution to follow regulations and their own protocols around establishing identity and rights for the other involved party, vs just sharing your username and password, which bypasses any sense of control or protocol around maintaining access to your accounts.

If you give someone your online banking username and password, **you** are liable for whatever they do. This could include stealing all of your money - which sounds terrible, but it's probably the least-harmful thing that could happen. Worse would be the third party using your account to facilitate crime (money laundering or scamming other innocent victims). **You** will be a party to those crimes and law enforcement will come knocking on your door. Not to mention, your financial institution may (legitimately) shut down your account and freeze your funds if there they suspect you're involved in fraud. They may even tell you that you're not allowed to bank with them any more, since giving out your online banking credentials violates their terms of use. This can be just as disruptive as having your money stolen.

If someone asks for your username and password, take the following steps:

- Discontinue communication with them immediately
- Report it to your bank. Even if nothing has happened to your account, they may be able to use information to help track down the criminal. It's common for criminals to target specific institutions, knowing the details of your case may help their anti-fraud department take action.
- Report it to the proper law enforcement or authorities. The US government maintains an [online safety](https://www.usa.gov/online-safety) website that includes resources to help you report crime appropriately.